# JQUERY when user types too quickly

Tags: php, jquery

I am working on search system and here is my html code

```
<input type="text" class="SearchChats" placeholder="Search">        
<div class="resc">

</div>
```

and this is my jquery/AJAX code

```
$(".SearchChats").keyup(function(e) {
    var val=$(this).val();
  if (e.which >= 47 && e.which <= 90 || e.which==8){
    if (val!="") {
        $(".resc").empty();
        $(".resc").show();
        $.ajax({
            url: '../files/connect.php',
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data:"SCTS="+val,
            success: function(ret)
            {
                $(".resc").append(ret);
            }
        });
        $(".overviewrap").hide();
    }else{
        $(".resc").hide();
        $(".overviewrap").show();
    }
}
});
```

and my connect.php

```
if (isset($_GET['SCTS'])) {
    $Value=$_GET['SCTS'];
    $Value=strtolower($_GET['SCTS']);
    $querya=$con->query("SELECT * FROM followers WHERE Follower='$NameId'");
    $followings=[];
    $count=0;
    while ($Folrow=$querya->fetch_row()) {
        $query=$con->query("SELECT Username FROM users WHERE Id='$Folrow[2]'");
        $Namerow=$query->fetch_row();
        $NameChat=$Namerow[0];
        if (strpos($NameChat, $Value) !== false) {
        $ProfilePicQuery=$con->query("SELECT Profile_pic FROM user_opt WHERE Username='$Folrow[2]'");
        $ProfilePicRow=$ProfilePicQuery->fetch_row();
           ?>
            <div class="overview">
                    <img src='../users/<?php echo $ProfilePicRow[0] ?>' class="overviewimg" />
                    <span class="overviewspan"><?php echo $NameChat;?></span>
            </div>
            <?php
            $count++;
        }
    }
```

The problem is when user types m it gives all users that start with `m` but when user types Murad really quickly it gives back user with name `Murad` but duplicates it 5 times(because it has got 5 charachters)

Comment: could you made a codepen with it? i think the solutions is putting a `timeOut()` and to prevent duplicated ajax calls. With your codepen would be easier to help you :)

Comment: @SandrinaPereira but coldpen has no php,has it?

Comment: Like Sandrina Pereira suggested, don't start search imediately. On receiving characters, wait f.e. 0.5 seconds before starting to search. If another character is entered, restart the timeout

Comment: @LarsStegelitz So should i put whole keyup function inside timeout or only ajax?

Comment: No, not the complete keyup. Inside keyup, check if a timer exists. If it exists, kill & recreate it, if not, just create it. The function thats executes when the timer is hits is the actual search with ajax.

Comment: @LarsStegelitz Could you do jsfiddle.Cause i did not fully understand your idea.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hjcg41xf/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you should add a timeout to decrease the number of ajax requests. Secondly, you can abort any ajax request while the user is still typing, and thirdly you should start search after a certain number of characters have been pressed.

Try the following:

```
var searchChatsTimeout = false;
var ajaxQuery = false;
$(".SearchChats").keyup(function(e) {

  clearTimeout(searchChatsTimeout);
  if (ajaxQuery !== false) {
    ajaxQuery.abort();
  }
  var val = $(this).val();

  if (val === '') {

      $(".resc").hide();
      $(".overviewrap").show();

      return;
  }

  searchChatsTimeout = setTimeout(function(){

            ajaxQuery = $.ajax({
                url: '../files/connect.php',
                type: 'GET',
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data:"SCTS="+val,
                success: function(ret)
                {
                     // Empty and Show .resc only if the query is successful
                     $(".resc").empty();
                     $(".resc").show();

                     $(".resc").append(ret);

                     // hide overviewrap if query is successful
                     $(".overviewrap").hide();
                }
            });


  }, 400);

});
```

Comment: Is this not possible without 
  if (val.length < 3) return;?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. I removed the check for val.length.

Comment: Mind-bogggling! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're using an ajax call everytime the user type, so this can be a bad practice, I think the best thing to do here is locate this call inside setTimeout function, and wait for user to stop typing, and to have a better performance, kill the past calls, add the ajax call into a variable, and kill it when another call will start, and use sync ajax calls

Comment: How do i detect when user stops typing??

Comment: "Note: Starting with Gecko 30.0 (Firefox 30.0 / Thunderbird 30.0 / SeaMonkey 2.27), synchronous requests on the main thread have been deprecated due to the negative effects to the user experience." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests

Answer (score 0):

Instead of appending, insert the text using

Instead of

```
$(".resc").append(ret);
```

use

```
$('.resc').innerHTML = 'Your text.';
```

Also, you can limit the call after entering 3 characters using and

instead of

```
if (val!="") {// call ajax}
```

use

```
if(val.length > 2){// call ajax}
```

Comment: Which line are you talking about?And why should i do this?

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are appending after each letter is typed. So for each letter combination the name matched, i.e: "M", "Mu", "Mur", Murad is appended into your options. Try to use the whole value of the field on keyup instead of just that letter which triggered the event.

Comment: Or you can do what Vijai has suggested, an alternate I was considering suggesting.

Comment: var val=$(this).val();

Comment: yea, sorry, then just stop appending and refill the element each time.